TYPO3 Content element translation colPos issue
I have a project TYPO3 v12.
After translating the content elements,
Content element are in connceted mode.
English is Main language uid = 0, German have uid = 1.
When i move a content element from section to section, Header (colPos =1) to main (colPos =0)
the colpos in the translated language is not following the original.
For Example after moving the content element (Text in English) colPos =0 , but in German the content element is still have colPos = 1. The right way is all sub-languages should follow the same colPos of the main language, so in the backend we could see them in the same section of the page.
Do you have an idea how to fix or is it a bug in TYPO3?

This seems to be a bug, which is quite old, since it has been reported for CMS 8 already.
https://forge.typo3.org/issues/88210
Just tested it with a "naked" CMS 12 core without Gridelements installed and still can reproduce it.

Thank you for your answer, i hope we get for a solution for this in the future.
